# How to make a condition when the ssm parameter does not exist

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-parameter-store

I'm creating a python code to insert multiple parameters to the parameter store.
The code I have already works as I wish, but I need to make a condition that if the parameter already exists it simply tells me that it already exists and I don't know what to put in the response condition

```
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm', "us-west-2")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  bucket =  'bucketjp1'
  key = 'output.json'

  obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
  data = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
  json_load = json.loads(data)

  row = range(len(json_load["Parameters"]))
  
  try:
    for i in row:
      value = json_load["Parameters"][i]
      response = ssm_client.get_parameter(
          Name=value["Name"]
      )
      
      if(response) //Here, if don't exists ???
      
        ssm_client.put_parameter(
          Name=value["Name"],
          Type=value["Type"],
          Value=value["Value"]
        )
            
        print("The parameter is inserted ", value["Name"])
        
      else:
        print("The parameter "+ value["Name"] + " is already exists.")
    
  Exception, e:
      raise e
```

If it runs it, it inserts and recognizes the ones that exist but it throws me this error:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ParameterAlreadyExists) when calling the PutParameter operation: The parameter already exists. To overwrite this value, set the overwrite option in the request to true.",
  "errorType": "ParameterAlreadyExists",
  "requestId": "e0f0fffb-21cd-4b06-a9b3-9691382874ba",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 29, in lambda_handler\n    ssm_client.put_parameter(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 391, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 719, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

I want to know if there is any special condition that I can place in the if or if I need to change my code

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into this, and found the only reply is not that useful so I did this, and it is working nicely:

```
import botocore
import boto3


def exist_ssm_param(param_name: str) -> bool:
    ssm = boto3.client('ssm', region_name='eu-north-1')

    try:
        response = ssm.get_parameter(
            Name=param_name
        )
        return True
    except ssm.exceptions.ParameterNotFound:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # in my scenario...
    print(exist_ssm_param(param_name="bucket_name"))        # True
    print(exist_ssm_param(param_name="foobar-no-exist"))    # False
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Catching exceptions is not always a good idea. For those who would like to avoid it, use [get-parameters](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ssm/get-parameters.html) instead and check if your parameter is in `InvalidParameters`:

```
import boto3

def get_ssm_parameter(name):
    ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm', 'us-west-2')
    parameters = ssm_client.get_parameters(Names=[name], WithDecryption=True)
    invalid_parameters = parameters.get('InvalidParameters')
    if invalid_parameters and name in invalid_parameters:
        return None
    return parameters['Parameters'][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got here and are looking for a TypeScript solution, the following might work:

```js
export class AwsConfigLoader {
  constructor(private readonly ssmClient: SSM) {}

  async getParameter(key: string): OptionalPromise<string> {
    const { Parameters: [Parameter] = [] } = await this.ssmClient.getParameters({
      Names: [key],
      WithDecryption: true,
    })

    return Parameter?.Value ?? process.env[key]
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

When you put a parameter to an existing one, it overwrites it only if you set the `overwrite` option to True. But this option is False by default. In your code, you haven't set it to True, so it doesn't overwrite and that's why, it renders the error message.

If you do not need to avoid overwriting, set the option to True. However, if you still want to check if a parameter exists or not, you can try something like this:

```
if ssm_client.get_parameter(Name=value["Name"])['Parameters'][0]['ARN']:
    # do something here if the parameter exists.
```

I haven't tried this, so you might need to check if it works. It should first check if the parameter exists by trying to retrieve its ARN. If it exists, then the execution continues accordingly.

Comment: This raises an exception if the parameter does not exist.